# How can I train a model and which model is best for this type of problem

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, deep-learning

Today I was working some keypoints detection over tabletop as shown in the image.[Table with annotations](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jS2US.jpg)

So I have around 100 images and 100 text files that contains coordinates for those 4 points on each image.
Text file format:
0.txt ---->
line(1) x1 x2 x3 x4
line(2) y1 y2 y3 y4
--------->
similarly for other 99 images and text files.

So I wanted to know how to train a model using this kind of dataset.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

There is no accurate and precise response to your question, however, since your dataset is not large you can forget about neural nets since they usually require a lot of data. You can apply HoG features on the image set and after standardizing the data apply different methods, most likely kNN will perform well.